# Do functional integrals have countable or uncountable infinite dimensions?

Tags: integration, functional-analysis

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_integration functional integrals can be written like
$$
\lim_{x->\infty}\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty{ ... \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty{ G[f] } }\prod_x df(x)
$$
But by using the product symbol $\prod$ this implies, that a functional integral has countable infinite dimensions. But is the space of functions used for functional integration really discrete and countable? I thought it is continuous/uncountable.

Comment: Probably best not to trust a section of a Wikipedia article that cites no sources, and even says at the very top "This section may be confusing to most readers." Also best no to trust something which says that the formal definition of _____ is some obscure symbol that has no meaning. What might be a good idea in this case is to go to the references section of that article and actually pick one of them up from a local library or the Arxiv. One of the relevant books cited at the bottom there can be found here: http://users.physik.fu-berlin.de/~kleinert/b5/

Comment: Thanks. I followed that link and found that in in chapter 2.1.2 of http://users.physik.fu-berlin.de/~kleinert/b5/psfiles/pthic02.pdf they say one takes a "continuum limit" from an expression with a product symbol to get a path integral. I guess that means that functional integrals (at least for path integrals) have uncountable infinite dimensions.